# python how to terminate a blocking thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, blocking

Blocking thread,i am not mean  loop or something.I mean,For example,thread run commmands.getoutput('cat'),because the shell command is waiting forever,so the thread will never  return.How can it notify the main thread,like saying "i have run for too long,i have come across something not good,kill me please?"

Comment: Side-note: You're aware that `commands` has been deprecated since Python 2.6 was released in 2008, right? `subprocess` has been around and a better replacement since 2.4.

Comment: Use subprocess and kill the pid

Comment: Actually killing threads from the outside is largely impossible. But if you can move to Python 3, the `subprocess` module has added `timeout` arguments to most blocking operations, so the `subprocess` module can end the command itself. The alternative is launching processes instead of threads (processes can be killed), using the `multiprocessing` module.

Comment: Yes,subprocess  works fine,it can stop a block process efficiently.But concurrent process  is seriously  restricted by cpu cores number. thanks ,if no better way,I just use multiprocessing  to work it out.thank again.  : )